# Request returns SSLError but openssl is OK

Tags: docker, ssl, certificate

When I trying to send a request from docker container I receive an error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='redmine.promomed.pro', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /issues/6081.json?include=journals (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

It looks that I haven't root or/and intermediate certs.

But when I send `openssl s_client -connect redmine.promomed.pro:443` from both docker container and simply from server where my docker I receive OK message:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R3, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign GCC R3 DV TLS CA 2020
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.promomed.pro
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*.promomed.pro
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign GCC R3 DV TLS CA 2020
---
Server certificate

...

    Start Time: 1678513281
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

It looks that my server has root and intermediate certs.
**And I know both my server and docker container has this certs**.

I'd be happy to get some advice and I'm ready to give more information if it demands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why it worked, but I fixed it by changing root and intermediate certs to chained cert in nginx conf.